# Accumulated reputation for tags

Tags: discussion, support

When we look at [Stack Overflow Trends comparing `django` and `flask`](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=django%2Cflask), we see *questions*. (Most of us will know how the majority of these questions look like.) I think that the mere number of questions doesn't tell us much about the adaptation of a technology, but about the quality of documentation, willingness to read and maybe the complexity of the matter.

On the other hand we have information about the top answerers for tags:

- ['django' Top Users - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/topusers)
- ['flask' Top Users - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flask/topusers)

Now the question:

- Is there information about the cumulative **reputation for tags** available? Where can I find it?
- Bonus questions:

  - If this information is not available, would a feature request have any chance of success?
  - Would you think the total yield of reputation on individual tags allow
    conclusions about a technology such as degree of diffusion or maturity?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I didn't know about [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Thanks a lot!